# $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ with $f(x,y) := (e^x\cos y, e^x\sin y)$ locally/globally reversible and Jacobian matrix

Tags: analysis, derivatives, inverse-function, jacobian

> Let $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ with $f(x,y) := (e^x\cos y, e^x\sin y)$
>
> I have to do the following things:
>
> 1. Prove that $f$ is locally reversible everywhere.
> 2. Is $f$ globally reversible? Why (not)?
> 3. Give a set $A \subset \mathbb{R}^2$, so that $f(A) =  \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{ \ ( 0,0 \ )\}$ and $f$  becomes globally reversible on
>      $A$
> 4. Determine the Jacobian matrix of the inverse image $f^{-1}: \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{ \ ( 0,0 \ )\} \to A$ in a point $a:=
>    (a_1,a_2) := (f_1(x,y),f_2(x,y))$.

The theorem for inverse functions and differentiation goes like that:

Let $D \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be open, $f:D \to \mathbb{R}^n$, $f \in C^1(D)$, $a \in D$ and $b := f(a)$ with $\det f'(a) \neq 0.$ Then there exists a $\delta > 0$ and an  open set $B \in \mathbb{R^n}$, so that we have:

i) $\det f'(x) \neq 0$ for all $x \in U_\delta(a)$

ii) $f: U_\delta(a) \to B$ is bijective

iii) $f^{-1}:B \to U_\delta(a)$ is continuously differentiable with $(f^{-1})'(y) = (f'(f^{-1}(y)))^{-1}$ (whereby $f^{-1}$ is the inverse function and $(f')^{-1}$ is the inverse Jacobian-matrix)

I know that $f(x,y) := (e^x\cos y, e^x\sin y)$ is continuously differentiable on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and

$$f'(x,y) = (e^x\cos y -e^x\sin y, e^x\sin y  e^x\cos y)$$

On $\mathbb{R}$ it has the determinant $e^x$ and furthermore,

$$f'(x,y)^{-1} = (e^{-x} \cos y e^{-x} \sin y, -e^{-x} \sin y e^{-x} \cos y)$$

So $f$ is locally reversible, but not globally reversible, because $f$ is periodic, i.e.

$$f(x,y) = f(x,y + 2k\pi)$$ with $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

I don't know if that is formally O.K. to answer 1. and 2. and I also don't know how to solve 3. and 4. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're on the right lines, though I'm not entirely sure if you typeset out the Jacobian out correctly with what you had in mind. It should be

$$ d_{(x,y)}f =
\begin{bmatrix}
e^{x}\cos y & e^{x}\sin y\\
-e^{x}\sin y & e^{x}\cos y
\end{bmatrix}
$$
which still has $\det d_{(x,y)}f = e^{x} \neq 0, $ for all $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^{2}$ like you said. I also agree with your reasoning between why $f$ is not globally invertible since it provides a counterexample, and also this looks like a question which acts as a hint for the next part.

$f$ is not globally invertible because of the periodic nature, so we can just restrict the domain from $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ to $A := \mathbb{R} \times (0, 2\pi )$, which remains surjective once one removes the origin from the image.

The last part is made a lot easier by noticing that the questions asks you to calculate the Jacobian at the point $(a,b) = (f_{1}(x,y), f_{2}(x,y)) \in A$, i.e. that $f^{-1}(a,b) = (x,y)$ (as we have proven now that $f$ is a bijection). So $(f^{-1} \circ f)(x,y) = (x,y)$, meaning that $d_{(x,y)}(f^{-1}\circ f) = \text{Id}$. But from the IFT we also know that
$$
d_{(a,b)}(f^{-1}) = (d_{(x,y)}f)^{-1},
$$
recalling that $(a,b)=f(x,y)$. I will leave the explicit calculations to you, but the final answer should be
$$ d_{(a,b)}(f^{-1}) = (d_{(x,y)}f)^{-1} =
\begin{bmatrix}
e^{-x}\cos y & -e^{-x}\sin y\\
e^{-x}\sin y & e^{-x}\cos y
\end{bmatrix}
$$